# An elegant way to implement delegation between a view controller and a sub model in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, delegation

I have an object, which serves as a model for a view controller. Call it *HomeScreenModel*. *HomeScreenModel* contains other sub models like *DeviceStateUpdateModel*, *NewFirmwareVersionCheckModel*, etc. *HomeScreenModel* serves as a kind of wrapper, but also implements it's own functionality. All of these models have their own public methods and defined protocols for delegation. For some of the sub models only a direct communication with the view controller is needed. That is, the *HomeScreenModel* serves only as a middleman between, say view controller and *DeviceStateUpdateModel*; it serves as a delegate for the *DeviceStateUpdateModel* and as a delegating object for the view controller. Accepting the call from *DeviceStateUpdateModel* and making the same call to the view controller.

Is there a better way to implement this, that doesn't involve duplicating the protocol methods from *DeviceStateUpdateModel* into the protocol of the *HomeScreenModel*? What kind of pattern to use if a model is to big to fit into one class and needs to be broken up, but still look as one whole model to the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the dependency into the `HomeScreenModel`, perhaps as a `typedef` of protocol(s).

So, to `HomeScreenModel` has something like:

```
typedef HomeScreenProtocolManager id<DeviceStateUpdateModelDelegate>;
```

Then `HomeScreenProtocolManager` has an initialiser such as:

```
- (instancetype) initWithProtocolManager:(HomeScreenProtocolManager *) protocolManager { ... };
```

Store this as a `protocolManager` as a property of the class and delegate to it. It is syntactically fine to include multiple protocols in the typedef.